# SQLite: Does PRIMARY KEY default to ASC?

Tags: sqlite

Ie, are the following two SQL statements equivalent in SQLite?

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC
);
```

Comment: Yes. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** they are.

There is no need to specify **ASC** and **beware** that if you were to specify **DESC**, then **NO** they are then not equivalent (see **4** below) as `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC` is an exclusion to the column being an alias of the **rowid** column as per :-

> The exception mentioned above is that if the declaration of a column
>   with declared type "INTEGER" includes an "PRIMARY KEY DESC" clause, it
>   does not become an alias for the rowid and is not classified as an
>   integer primary key. This quirk is not by design. It is due to a bug
>   in early versions of SQLite. But fixing the bug could result in
>   backwards incompatibilities. Hence, the original behavior has been
>   retained (and documented) because odd behavior in a corner case is far
>   better than a compatibility break.

[ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

You can use `id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(id, DESC)`, but still the order defaults to ASC when retrieving the column as it is an alias of the rowid (see **5** below )

Perhaps consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts1;
CREATE TABLE posts1 (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts2;
CREATE TABLE posts2 (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts3;
CREATE TABLE posts3 (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts4;
CREATE TABLE posts4 (
    id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id DESC)
);

INSERT INTO posts1 VALUES(null),(null),(null);
INSERT INTO posts2 VALUES(null),(null),(null);
INSERT INTO posts3 VALUES(null),(null),(null);
INSERT INTO posts4 VALUES(null),(null),(null);

SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name LIKE '%posts%';

SELECT * FROM posts1;
SELECT * FROM posts2;
SELECT * FROM posts3;
SELECT * FROM posts4;
```

## Results

### 1

The query `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name LIKE '%posts%';` results in :-

[image]

As you can see **posts3** is significantly different as the index **sqlite_autoindex_posts3_1** has been created

The others do not have a specific index created as the id column is an alias of the **rowid** column

> The data for rowid tables is stored as a B-Tree structure containing
>   one entry for each table row, using the rowid value as the key. This
>   means that retrieving or sorting records by rowid is fast. Searching
>   for a record with a specific rowid, or for all records with rowids
>   within a specified range is around twice as fast as a similar search
>   made by specifying any other PRIMARY KEY or indexed value.

[ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

### 2

The query `SELECT * FROM posts1;` results in :-

[image]

### 3

The query `SELECT * FROM posts2;`, confirms the initial **YES** answer as per :-

[image]

### 4

The query `SELECT * FROM posts3;`, may be a little confusing, but shows that `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC` does not result in an alias of the **rowid** and in the case of no value or null being inserted into the column, the value is null rather than an auto generated value. There is no UNIQUE constraint conflict (as nulls are considered as being different values).

[image]

### 5

The query `SELECT * FROM posts4;` produces the same result as for 1 and 2 even though `id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id DESC)` was used. Confirming that even if **DESC** is applied via the column definition that the sort order is still defaults to **ASC** (unless the ORDER BY clause is used).

- Note that this peculiarity is specific to the **rowid** column or an alias thereof.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See both https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid and  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html for a more complete answer.  Shawn's link is specific to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` which matches the example code, but the more general question is not answered explicitly in either location, but can be deduced by reading both.

Under SQL Data Constraints, the first link says

> In most cases, UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints are implemented by creating a unique index in the database. (The exceptions are INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and PRIMARY KEYs on WITHOUT ROWID tables.)

The CREATE INDEX page explains that originally the sort order was ignored and all indices were generated in ascending order.  Only as of version 3.3.0 is the `DESC` order "understood".  But even that description is somewhat vague, however altogether it is apparent that **ASC is the default**.