# What is the purpose of the DESC and ASC after PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: sqlite

What is the difference between this:

```
CREATE TABLE posts1 (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC
);
```

and this:

```
CREATE TABLE posts1 (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC
);
```

I know that `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC` doesn't turn `id` column into the alias of `rowid`.

I'm interested in the initial purpose of the `DESC` and `ASC` after `PRIMARY KEY`? What are they for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite: Does PRIMARY KEY default to ASC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877612/sqlite-does-primary-key-default-to-asc)

Comment: no, it doesn't. it is written there that `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC` doesn't turn id column into the alias of rowid. that's all. nothing about the purpose of these things. @DarkBee

Comment: "*it does not become an alias for the rowid and is not classified as an integer primary key. **This quirk is not by design. It is due to a bug in early versions of SQLite**. But fixing the bug could result in backwards incompatibilities*" - MikeT

Comment: so `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC` does nothing at all except prevents the column from being the alias of `rowid` ?

Comment: Seems like it, look at example **5** posted by MikeT  - "*Confirming that even if DESC is applied via the column definition that the sort order is still defaults to ASC (unless the ORDER BY clause is used)*"

Comment: Most likely, SQLite has the ability to traverse the primary key `id` column either in order or in reverse.  Therefore, the sort direction only determines the structure of the B tree, but should have no other effect on the queries you write.

Comment: @DarkBee then, what is the difference between `PRIMARY KEY (id DESC)` and `PRIMARY KEY (id ASC)` ? Although, @Tim Biegeleisen has already written the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of ASC or DESC on a column of a PRIMARY KEY is to allow that column to be ordered and other than INTEGER types, subsequently described, the difference would simply be the order of the index.

**However**, when it comes to the specific/special instance of an INTEGER type (and it being the only column in the Primary Key) it ended up instead as determining if or if not the column was then an alias of the rowid column (a bug admitted to but retained for compatibility).

- At a guess, implementing a reversal of the rowid indexing may have had an impact on the superior efficiency of the rowid *(Access to records via rowid is highly optimized and very fast.)*.

For other types (even implied/derived INTEGER types (e.g. INT)) when the resultant PRIMARY KEY has already been ruled as as being an alias of the rowid, then the true purpose is applied, i.e. the index is ordered accordingly.

Using the answer/discussion referenced i.e. [SQLite: Does PRIMARY KEY default to ASC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877612/sqlite-does-primary-key-default-to-asc)

Then extending this to include:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts5;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts5 (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY ASC
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts6;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts6 (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY DESC
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts7;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts7 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY ASC
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts8 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY DESC
);
```

- i.e. where the PRIMARY KEY will not be an alias of the rowid BEFORE consideration of the order dues to ASC/DESC.

And then loaded with data as per :-

```
INSERT INTO posts5 VALUES('Z'),('A'),('M');
INSERT INTO posts6 VALUES('Z'),('A'),('M');
INSERT INTO posts7 VALUES('Z'),('A'),('M');
INSERT INTO posts8 VALUES('Z'),('A'),('M');
```

And finally:-

```
SELECT * FROM posts5 GROUP BY id /* group by used to force/trick use of the PK not the b-tree/rowid index*/;
SELECT * FROM posts6 GROUP BY id /* group by used to force/trick use of the PK not the b-tree/rowid index*/;
SELECT * FROM posts7 GROUP BY id /* group by used to force/trick use of the PK not the b-tree/rowid index*/;
SELECT * FROM posts8 GROUP BY id /* group by used to force/trick use of the PK not the b-tree/rowid index*/;
```

Then the results are:-

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

- i.e. they are ordered according to the PK not the rowid and thus according to ASC/DESC and thus the intended use.
- see the referenced answer for results for when the rowid is aliased.